# Php regex: replacing localization string

Tags: php, regex, templating

The Stackoverflow user Casimir et Hippolyte gave me this awesome function to replace strings like **[[ Something ]]** with localized strings being returned with **$this->_()** function.

```
$that = $this;
$view = preg_replace_callback('~\[\[\K(?>[^]]++|](?!]))*~', function ($m) use ($that) {
   return $that->__($m[0]); }, $view);
```

It works except that it doesn't replace the brackets. So, if I have **"Yes|Ja"** my I18n file, and in my view file I write **[[ Yes ]]** it comes up with **[[ Ja ]]**.

I've spent a few hours trying and googling but unfortunately - nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can replace your pattern by:

```
$that = $this;
$view = preg_replace_callback(
        '~\[\[((?:[^]]+|](?!]))*+)]]~', function ($m) use ($that) {
        return $that->__($m[1]); }, $view);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will capture the two square brackets  `\K\[\[(?>[^]]++|](?!]))]]*`

**Input Text**

```
like [[ yes|ja ]] with
```

**Matches**

```
[0] => [[ yes|ja ]]
[1] => yes|ja
```

I"m not a python programmer, but I think you'll want to modify your script to be like this:

```
$that = $this;
$view = preg_replace_callback('~\K\[\[(?>[^]]++|](?!]))]]*~', function ($m) use ($that) {
   return $that->__($m[1]); }, $view);
```